# Access items from a ListView ItemSource in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have the following ListView and associated template:

```
listView = new ListView()
        {
            ItemTemplate = dtemplate
        };
        listView.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("Items"));

var dtemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
        {
            var stacklayout = new StackLayout()
            {
                Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal
            };
            var lbl = new Label();
            lbl.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Title")); //<-- this
            stacklayout.Children.Add(lbl);
            return new ViewCell { View = stacklayout };
        });
```

Referring to the line marked "//<-- this", How do I set the binding programmatically without using a text literal, is there no way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `nameof(SomeProperty)` to get the Property name as a string

Comment: This didn't really answer the question I had In my head but I didn't ask it very well.  Your answer is definitely a good answer though.  What I'm wondering is if there is any way to access the independent item from the items collection that was passed into the template, and then how to access that individual item and use it for binding.

Comment: `"{Binding .}"` will access the bound object